# Realm non looper thread with callback

Tags: java, android

I am an Android developer,
and i decided to use realm inside my app.

I implemented push notification so when i get a push from the server i want to update the database and get notification when commit is finished.
I tried realm.executeTransactionAsync but it didn't get callback when it has finished i think it because it opened from a non-Looper thread .
So i tried  realm.executeTransaction(Transaction,Callback)
But it was deprecated on ver 1.0.0 so i cannot use it.

So now i use ver 1.0.0 but i cannot understand how can i get a success callback for an transaction inside non looper thread like a Service?

Answer (score 0):

First- the UI thread is by default associated with a `Looper`. You can check by calling- `realm.isAutoRefresh()`.

According the [API](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/) you can use:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {

        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i already tried executeTransactionAsync but the OnSuccess never called .

Comment: Checked it and it worked. Please post your code (`onReceive()` method)